# Elastic search undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I used `mongo-connector` on my linux server

`pip install mongo-connector`

`python mongo_connector.py -m localhost:27217 -t http://localhost:9200`

**Inside my local node.js server I am using mongoDB which is hosted on my linux server**

```
var Movie = require('../models/Movie');
var mongoosastic = require("mongoosastic");
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

movie = new Movie({title: 'Warrior'});

movie.save(function() {
  console.log(arguments)
  Movie.search({query:"Warrior"}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

**Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var mongoosastic = require("mongoosastic");

var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  language: String,
  year: String,
  title: { type:String, es_indexed:true },
  director: String

});


movieSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

I keep getting undefined. I think the data is indexed, but I can't search for it.

**Testing**

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert' -d '{ "name" : "Dilbert Brown" }'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert?pretty=true'

{
  "_index" : "blog",
  "_type" : "user",
  "_id" : "dilbert",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{ "name" : "Dilbert Brown" }
}
```

The problem could be that node.js is hosted on my local machine and the mongoDB/elasticsearch is on my linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pointing at the fact that your node.js and ES are on two different hosts, you've probably put the finger on the issue.

Looking, at your command line :

```
python mongo_connector.py -m localhost:27217 -t http://localhost:9200
```

1. `-m` points to your Mongo DB on the localhost port 27217 (unless that port is the entry to an SSH tunnel to your remote linux server)
2. `-t` points to your replication endpoint (i.e. Elasticsearch on port 9200 of your local machine)

According to your statement that Elasticsearch and MongoDB are hosted on your remote linux server, you should replace `localhost` with the host name or IP address of your Linux server and make sure the ports 27217 and 9200 are open on that host.

Then you should also make sure that your Node.js and mongoosastic points to your linux server, because by default it uses `localhost:9200`, i.e. your local machine. So use this instead and point to your linux server:

```
movieSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  hosts: [
    'your_linux_host:9200'
  ]
});
```

And also that your mongoose connection points to your linux server as well.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://your_linux_host/your_database');
```

Comment: I ran `python mongo_connector.py -m localhost:27217 -t http://localhost:9200` on my server though, so localhost is the server.

Comment: Also make sure to properly connect `mongoose` to your remote linux server. See above.

Comment: Thanks, but I definitely did that. The models are saving to mongoDB fine. I am going to try https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-go-and-revel-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-x64-vps

Comment: Try `Movie.search({query_string:{query:"Warrior"}})`

Comment: Nope It seems to still return undefined. I will have to think of something, this should help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-go-and-revel-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-x64-vps but go is not being nice

Comment: No because when I try to install transform with go I am getting an issue with the version of go, and I had a hard time updating the version, hurdle after hurdle lol so I moved onto some frontend stuff, but I will give it another shot today.